# SQL Where clause by date in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering why this where clause isn't working in MySql? I have the column of runDate set to the data type "date" and the date appears in the format below:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("***","***","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ArnoldsPizzaShop", $con);




$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM runinfo WHERE runDate = 2013-01-06");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo  $row['route'] ;
 }


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Did you try putting quotes around the date? `WHERE runDate = '2013-01-06'`

Comment: Well, so once more: `mysql`-extension is outdated, not maintained anymore and will be flagged as deprecated. Use `PDO_MYSQL`, or `MySQLi` instead. http://php.net/mysql-connect

Comment: try: 'WHERE runDate = DATE('2013-01-06');'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need single quotes around the date value:

```
SELECT * 
FROM runinfo 
WHERE runDate = '2013-01-06'
```

So your code would be:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM runinfo WHERE runDate = '2013-01-06'");
```

If your `runDate` column also contains the time, then you might want to use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM runinfo 
WHERE Date(runDate) = '2013-01-06'
```

Or even:

```
SELECT * 
FROM runinfo 
WHERE runDate between '2013-01-06' and '2013-01-07'
```

Comment: yeh ive tried that and it still doesnt work. Its weird because if I match by the column ID it works fine

Comment: @MattJameson when you say doesn't work, do you get an error? Can you elaborate? Are you sure there is data that matches the date?  Does it also have time stored with it?

Comment: without the quotes, the date is see as subtraction, e.g. 2013 minus 1 minus 6 = 2006.

Comment: @MarcB I think you need some math help ;). 2013-1-6 = 2006. But yeah, we'll need more than "it doesn't work"

Comment: hmm it hasnt got a time in it, its just down as the data type 'date' i'm not getting an error i'm just getting nothing back from the query

Comment: @MattJameson Could you update your question with some sample rows of data as well as the result of `DESCRIBE TABLE table_name`

Comment: @MattJameson are you sure there is data that matches that date?

Comment: @MattJameson you can also try placing the `date()` function around your string -- `date('2013-01-06')` -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8509f/4